# Does Chan Marshall's stage name "Cat Power" have a specific meaning?

Tags: psychology

I know that a general question about stage names already exists [here](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/44/138), but I was wandering if in the specific case of American songwriter Chan Marshall her stage name has a strong meaning or if it is used for some of the reasons already listed in the aforementioned SE question.

Has Chan Marshall/Cat Power ever told why she had chosen her stage name and what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per the Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_Power):

> Marshall began playing music in Atlanta with a collective of musicians
>   made up of Glen Thrasher, Marc Moore, Damon Moore and Fletcher
>   Liegerot, who would get together for jam sessions in a basement. **The
>   group were booked for a show and had to come up with a name quickly,
>   when a man walked through the door of the pizzeria where Marshall
>   worked, wearing a Caterpillar trucker cap that read: "Cat Diesel
>   Power"**. Marshall immediately decided on Cat Power as the name of the
>   band.